# Apache, and logrotate instances

Tags: apache-2.2, logrotate

If I have one website and I want to rotate its logs, there's one instance of logrotate that is launched.
There are as many logrotate instances launched as they are virtual websites.

Here you can find mod_log_rotate, with a 1.3 version and (only) 2.0 version:

http://www.hexten.net/wiki/index.php/Mod-log-rotate

It's 6 years old.
Is there something new, or maybe is there something like that in recent Apache versions?

I didn't find anything like that, and I don't know if this code is still "usable" for recent Apache versions (2.2.x)

Don't hesitate to edit my post to make it proper English, thanks a lot!

Comment: This looks like it would be better suited to ServerFault.com .

Answer (score 0):

The author himself answered:

### Olivier à andya

Hi!

May I ask you a question?
It's about mod_log_rotate you've written 6 years ago.

http://www.hexten.net/wiki/index.php/Mod-log-rotate

Did you make something new, or maybe is there something like that in recent Apache versions?

Thank you very much, and thank you very much to give your code to the community, so few people do...

Have a nice day,

Olivier

### Andy Armstrong

Hi Olivier,

The apache2 version will work fine with Apache 2.2 - I'm using it in production with Apache 2.2 myself.

--
Andy Armstrong, Hexten

;)